# Followed Laravel Fundamentals tutorial, issue with episode 9 on MVC

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently following through the Laravel Fundamentals tutorial videos as I tried another tutorial before but it didn't explain Laravel in as much detail.

I'm now onto episode 9 (https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/9) however once I get to the `show($id)` function in my controller I get errors with `findOrFail()` or if I just use `find()` it simply doesn't query and return anything.

I have followed the tutorial pretty much to a T other than changing "Articles" to "Posts" as I preferred the naming.

I honestly want to bash my head into a wall at this point as I have no clue why this is happening.

I've checked over all my syntax and it seems to be in order. Also the query for `Article::all();` in the index returns data from my DB Table.

app/Http/Controllers/PostsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }
}
```

routes/web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');

Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostsController@show');
```

app/Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body'
    ];
}
```

The error I receive when I use findOrFail()

```
(2/2) NotFoundHttpException
No query results for model [App\Post] 1

in Handler.php line 131
```

Thanks, I hope someone can see where I am going wrong!

Comment: Are you set primary key of post table?

Comment: can you provide blade file code where is show link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no entry in my table with the ID '1'

I feel so dumb...

Comment: You got my vote+, even it's beginers mistake, you got it on your own! Keep it up and good luck! :) By the way, Google about Rubber duck debugging  =)

Comment: Only a beginner with laravel, just need to note to not re-use database tables :D

Answer (score 0):

If you set primary key of id for `post` table :

app/Post.php

```
<?php
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\model;


 /**
  * 
  */
  class Post extends Model
  {

     protected $primaryKey = 'id'; 
     public $timestamps = false;
     protected $table = 'post'; //your table name
  }
```

Comment: All sorted, refer to my comment

Answer (score -1):

I think it is possible that your database table is not named correctly. The table should be called "posts". If it is named anything else, you need to declare it in your Post model:

```
protected $table = "name of your database table";
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't change anything, should've mentioned I tried this. As stated it does connect to the database and display the data in the index() function, however the find($id) doesn't return anything